# Harry Potter fanfic in which the war is over and Harry is working at the Ministry of Magic

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction

I'm looking for a Harry Potter fanfic in which the war is over and Harry is working at the Ministry of Magic (he defeated Voldy, I guess). However, he was never tested for his classification (or he was already tested but he suppressed his instinct). I cannot remember whether this fic classification is what... likely usual A/B/O? I can't remember whether this is happy or bad. I also cannot remember who went and reclassified him... caught him maybe?

I think I might mixed up the story line. The one regarding little is "These Little Day". This is not a sexual age regression fic.

Comment: Do you remember what this "classification" meant? How do you get tested for it? Did his job have to do with testing classifications? What did classification have to do with the plot?

Comment: OP you appear to have more than one account. You should try and get them merged so that you can interact with the site properly - e.g., edit your own posts and accept answers to your questions. As well as that you will also be able to gain rep properly and unlock the site's functions and so on. You can see that your original account already has 14 points and one badge, but your new accounts start again

Comment: @Aralaiqualasse Please consider merging your accounts, as Au101 suggests. You can do this using the instructions [here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).

Comment: To Au101 and Rand al'Thor ...Thanks for the help and tip. I didn't even know I accidentally created two account with same name. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like [Hidden Secrets Found](https://web.archive.org/web/20170121152752/http://archiveofourown.org/works/7379074/chapters/16762081):

> After several long years of hiding what he truly is and making sure to skip out of the mandatory testing Harry Potter's time is up. Thanks to three certain males Harry suddenly finds his world shaped into what it should of been, not what Dumbledore and the Dursley's wanted it to be.

Comment: Can you provide snippets of the text to help identify more similarities? Spoilers are allowed and often encouraged as they help identify the story and anybody on the question will likely have read the question and be content with spoilers!

Answer (score 5):

This sounds like "[Harry Potter and the Classification Potion](https://www.fanfiction.net/s/12278669/1/Harry-Potter-and-the-Classification-Potion)".

> Every witch and wizard was tested with this potion in their last year
>   of hogwarts. Once ingested an aura would glow around the person's
>   body, the colour of the aura would tell the drinker what
>   classification they fell into. The person would then go on and live in
>   the life style that was best suited for them.
>
> The classifications were: Alpha, Omega, Master, Pet, Neutral, Guardian
>   and littles. Neutrals, Alphas and Omega took up the most of the
>   population, Master and Pet were a close second, Guardians and Littles
>   were close to being called rare.
>
> Severus himself had taken the potion when he was seventeen and had
>   scoffed at the results, he was not a guardian and anyone who had met
>   him could attest to that. The only person that had known his true
>   classification was Dumbledore, Snape had told everyone else that he
>   had tested as a Master and no one had doubted him.

And then

> Potter, was a little

Comment: For the record, this isn't the worst Harry Potter fanfic but only because "My Immortal" exists.

Comment: Soooo, I almost don’t want to ask, but what does it mean to test as a “little”?

Comment: @Adamant - Click on the link and have a read. It's not especially long.

Comment: That was...incredibly bad.

Comment: I got through two chapters and gave up. To spare future readers the effort, a  "little" basically means Harry regresses to a infantile state where he wears a diaper, has a stuffed turtle, and drinks milk from a baby bottle. Snape becomes his Daddy/Guardian (not sexual, thank god). So its an age-play slash-fic. And now, if you'll excuse me, I'm going to take a shower.

Comment: @ApproachingDarknessFish Thank you for your sacrifice.